# mysql connector fails falling back to master after failover to slave

Tags: database, glassfish, mysql-connector

I have a master/slave mysql (mariadb) setup for replication. Is it possible to let an existing database connection fallback to master when it's available again after a failover to slave has happened? I'm using Glassfish connection pools and have tried with different properties with no effect, eg. secondsBeforeRetryMaster. My URL is: jdbc:mysql:sequential://master,slave/db

I'm following

[mysql connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-config-failover.html)

It works when new connections are created, but for existing ones, fallback does not happen at all. Since I'm reusing existing connections a lot, I'm kind of lost. The secondary server is read-only, so all writes to database fail after a failover.